# Virgola o no in avviso bancomat?

Tags: punctuation

La maggior parte dei bancomat in Italia propone un avviso di questo tipo:

> Al prelievo verrà applicata una commissione, se previsto dalla sua
>   banca.

La mia domanda riguarda la virgola dopo commissione. Circa metà delle banche la mettono, le altre no.

Vorrei capire se solo una delle versioni è corretta, se lo sono entrambe e per quali motivi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accenno di risposta rapida: la virgola può benissimo esserci come non esserci.

Esistono infiniti controesempi alla pseudoregoletta per cui non vada messa se la protasi segue l'apodosi (cioè se la condizione con il “se...” segue la proposizione principale).
Uno dei primissimi esempi di periodo ipotetico nell'*Italiano* di Serianni è, testualmente:

> penso che potremmo andare al cinema, se ti andasse (XIV, 146)

o, in Manzoni,

> Le prometto che fo uno sproposito, se lei non mi dice subito subito il nome di colui (*I promessi sposi*, cap. II)

o, in *Se questo è un uomo* di Primo Levi,

> A dare un colpo di spugna al passato e al futuro si impara assai presto, se il bisogno preme.

(Viceversa, non sta scritto da nessuna parte che debba esserci necessariamente una virgola dopo la protasi:

> Se dovessero uccidervi domani col vostro bambino voi non gli dareste oggi da mangiare?

scrive Primo Levi, e

> se si perde un bottone bisogna saperselo riattaccare con un filo di ferro.

In generale, a differenza di altre lingue come il tedesco, l'italiano è molto tollerante quanto alla presenza o assenza di virgole fra principali e subordinate, e usarle o meno contribuisce anzi al senso da dare alla frase.)

Answer (score 1):

Secondo la pagina Wikipedia in merito alla proposizione condizionale (https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposizione_condizionale)
la virgola non si usa se si mette la conseguenza/premessa prima della condizione.

Nel caso della tua frase:

Conseguenza/premessa = Al prelievo verrà applicata una commissione

Condizione = Se previsto dalla sua banca.

Quindi secondo questa regola la versione corretta sarebbe quella senza virgola, ma come parlante madrelingua non lo sento come sbagliato il fatto di metterla.

Tuttavia, se la frase fosse ribaltata:
*Se previsto dalla sua banca, al prelievo verrà applicata una commissione* allora la virgola ci vuole assolutamente (almeno secondo la mia percezione).

Comment: Non prenderei la Wikipedia come fonte... :)

Comment: Concordo (da madrelingua) sulla necessità della virgola nella versione ribaltata. Nella frase originale mi stupisce che le banche, normalmente attente alla comunicazione, siano giunte a conclusioni opposte sulla necessità della virgola in quella frase, che con minuscole varianti propongono tutte.